# Dropdown menu mobile phone not working

Tags: html, css, mobile, twitter-bootstrap-3, drop-down-menu

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="dropdown">
  <a class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
      Dropdown
      <span class="caret"></span>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-messages">
    <li><a href="profile"><i class=ti-user></i>&nbsp; Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="logoutGeneral"><i class=ti-layout-sidebar-left></i>&nbsp; Logout</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-messages"></ul>
```

i am using the class above with

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-messages">
<li><a href="profile"><i class=ti-user></i>&nbsp; Profile</a></li>
<li><a href="logoutGeneral"><i class=ti-layout-sidebar-left></i>&nbsp; Logout</a></li>
</ul>
```

this code of course works fine on computer browsers but if i try to do the same with my mobile phone it doesnt work, how may i fix this issue?

Comment: What do you mean by 'not working'? Can you create a snippet

Comment: When i click any elements in the dropdown list it doenst redirect me if i am using my mobile phone, it only closes the dropdown list

Comment: What happens on mobile when you click the link? You may get more help with a more complete snippet

Comment: try again please

Comment: Try what? The snippet works fine when I resize the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem some time ago. Solution is simple, try to change hierarchy of HTML.

Just insert `dropdown-menu` above `dropdown` like this:

```html
<div class="dropdown">

  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-messages">
    <li><a href="profile"><i class=ti-user></i>&nbsp; Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="logoutGeneral"><i class=ti-layout-sidebar-left></i>&nbsp; Logout</a></li>
  </ul>
  <a class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
      Dropdown
      <span class="caret"></span>
  </a>

</div>
```

Should work.